# How to return a Ruby array intersection with duplicate elements? (problem with bigrams in Dice Coefficient)

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, intersection, match

I'm trying to script Dice's Coefficient, but I'm having a bit of a problem with the array intersection.

```
def bigram(string)
  string.downcase!
  bgarray=[]
  bgstring="%"+string+"#"
  bgslength = bgstring.length
  0.upto(bgslength-2) do |i|
    bgarray << bgstring[i,2]
   end
   return bgarray
 end

def approx_string_match(teststring, refstring)
  test_bigram = bigram(teststring) #.uniq
  ref_bigram = bigram(refstring)   #.uniq

  bigram_overlay = test_bigram & ref_bigram

  result = (2*bigram_overlay.length.to_f)/(test_bigram.length.to_f+ref_bigram.length.to_f)*100

  return result
end
```

The problem is, as & removes duplicates, I get stuff like this:

```
string1="Almirante Almeida Almada"
string2="Almirante Almeida Almada"

puts approx_string_match(string1, string2) => 76.0%
```

It should return 100.

The uniq method nails it, but there is information loss, which may bring unwanted matches in the particular dataset I'm working.

How can I get an intersection with all duplicates included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `Yuval F` said you should use `multiset`. However, there is no`multiset` in Ruby standard library , Take at look at [here](http://maraigue.hhiro.net/multiset/index-en.php) and [here](http://rubyforge.org/projects/multiset/).

If performance is not that critical for your application, you still can do it using`Array` with a little bit code.

```
def intersect  a , b  
    a.inject([]) do |intersect, s|
      index = b.index(s)
      unless index.nil?
         intersect << s
         b.delete_at(index)
      end
      intersect        
    end
end

a=  ["al","al","lc" ,"lc","ld"]
b = ["al","al" ,"lc" ,"ef"]
puts intersect(a ,b).inspect   #["al", "al", "lc"]
```

Comment: I appreciate it pierr. The code u posted does the trick =) ty

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Dice%27s_coefficient) I believe you should not use Ruby's sets but rather multisets, so that every bigram gets counted the number of times it appears. Maybe you can use [this gem](http://rubyforge.org/projects/multiset/) for multisets. This should give a correct behavior for recurring bigrams.

Answer (score 0):

I toyed with this, based on the answer from @pierr, for a while and ended up with this.

```
a = ["al","al","lc","lc","lc","lc","ld"]
b = ["al","al","al","al","al","lc","ef"]
result=[]
h1,h2=Hash.new(0),Hash.new(0)
a.each{|x| h1[x]+=1}
b.each{|x| h2[x]+=1}
h1.each_pair{|key,val| result<<[key]*[val,h2[key]].min if h2[key]!=0}
result.flatten
```

`=> ["al", "al", "lc"]`

This could be a kind of multiset intersect of `a` & `b` but don't take my word for it because I haven't tested it enough to be sure.