# How can I check if a Ruby array includes one of several values?

Tags: ruby, string, arrays, intersect

I have two Ruby arrays, and I need to see if they have any values in common. I could just loop through each of the values in one array and do include?() on the other, but I'm sure there's a better way. What is it? (The arrays both hold strings.)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you care what elements it has in common?

Comment: Nope. All I want to know is if the two have any elements in common at all.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

[Set intersect](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002212) them:

```
a1 & a2
```

Here's an example:

```
> a1 = [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
> a2 = [ 'bar', 'baz' ]
> a1 & a2
=> ["bar"]
> !(a1 & a2).empty? # Returns true if there are any elements in common
=> true
```

Comment: well, the OP wants "to check", so a boolean result would be a better fit: !(a1 & a2).empty?

Comment: I'd go with (a1 & a2).any? instead of !(a1 & a2).empty?

Comment: @rilla `any?` works in this case, but not when dealing with `false` and `nil` values: `[nil, false].any? #=> false`.

Comment: is there a neater way to do `!(a1 & a2).empty?`?

Comment: @DavidWest yes, `(a1 & a2).present?`.

Comment: @Maurice note that `#present?` requires `ActiveSupport`, so it isn't a straight Ruby solution.

Answer (score 8):

Any value in common ? you can use the intersection operator : [&](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002212)

```
[ 1, 1, 3, 5 ] & [ 1, 2, 3 ]   #=> [ 1, 3 ]
```

If you are looking for a full intersection however (with duplicates) the problem is more complex there is already a stack overflow here : [How to return a Ruby array intersection with duplicate elements? (problem with bigrams in Dice Coefficient)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600168/how-to-return-a-ruby-array-intersection-with-duplicate-elements-problem-with-bi)

Or a quick [snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2134) which defines "real_intersection" and validates the following test

```
class ArrayIntersectionTests < Test::Unit::TestCase    
  def test_real_array_intersection
    assert_equal [2], [2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 13, 49] & [2, 2, 2, 5, 11, 107]
    assert_equal [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 13, 49].real_intersection([2, 2, 2, 5, 11, 107])
    assert_equal ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'] & ['a', 'c', 'a', 'd']
    assert_equal ['a', 'a', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'].real_intersection(['a', 'c', 'a', 'd'])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Using intersection looks nice, but it is inefficient. I would use "any?" on the first array (so that iteration stops when one of the elements is found in the second array). Also, using a Set on the second array will make membership checks fast. i.e.:

```
a = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
b = Set.new([:c, :d, :e, :f])
c = [:a, :b, :g, :h]

# Do a and b have at least a common value?
a.any? {|item| b.include? item}
# true

# Do c and b have at least a common value?
c.any? {|item| b.include? item}
#false
```

Comment: Benchmarking shows this to be 1.5-2x faster than the (more aesthetically pleasing) set intersection method, depending on simple value versus object attribute comparison. Set intersection using `any?` instead of `empty?`, as suggested in a comment above, varied slightly, but didn't change the outcome. (Strictly considering performance, and as expected since `any?` bails on the first match.)

Answer (score 5):

### Array#intersect? (Ruby 3.1+)

Starting from Ruby 3.1, there is a new `Array#intersect?` method,
which checks whether two arrays have at least one element in common.

Here is an example:

```rb
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = [7, 8, 9]

# 3 is the common element
a.intersect?(b)
# => true

# No common elements
a.intersect?(c)
# => false
```

Also, `Array#intersect?` can be much faster than alternatives since it avoids creating an intermediate array, returns true as soon as it finds a common element, it is implemented in C.

**Sources:**

- [Ruby 3.1 adds Array#intersect?](https://bigbinary.com/blog/ruby-3-1-adds-array-intersect).
- [Pull Request](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/1972).
- [Discussion](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15198).
- [Source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/08de37f9fa3469365e6b5c964689ae2bae0eb9f3/array.c#L5575).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a1 = [ 'foo', 'bar' ] 
a2 = [ 'bar', 'baz' ]
a1-a2 != a1
true
```